# Postgres bg writer checkpointWriteTimeInMillisecondsPerSecond is more than a second per second

Tags: postgresql

I have a metric that is reported as part of my standalone postgres installation.

```
bgwriter.checkpointSyncTimeInMillisecondsPerSecond
```

Total amount of time that has been spent in the portion of checkpoint processing where files are synchronized to disk, in milliseconds.

As seen on the graph it is showing that every 5 minute of so the max value for this metric jumps to values far higher than 1 second.

[image]

Is it a reason for concern (the fact that it is more than a second per second)?
What exactly does it impact?
Which PG settings potentially can help me reduce it if needed?

Thanks

Comment: no, there is no concern, every database, makes it maintenance, so the spikes are normla

Comment: PostgreSQL does not publish such a metric, at least not under that label.  Your issue seems to be with how some unnamed monitoring tool chooses to rename things.

Comment: @jjanes, that is correct, I don't know the exact metric name in postgres but I posted its exact definition

Total amount of time that has been spent in the portion of checkpoint processing where files are synchronized to disk, in milliseconds.

And my questions here is - is there any value of that metric (that is explained in words) that I need to be looking out for? When a database is spending more than 1 second per second to write blocks to disk (how I understand it), is it a reason for concerns? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It is the "per second" part that is confusing. The data must ultimately stem from `pg_stat_bgwriter`, which has a column `checkpoint_sync_time` which contains the total milliseconds spent on syncing files to disk during checkpoints and is updated **once** at the end of a checkpoint.

The inane monitoring tool you are using seems to take regular snapshots of that view and divide the difference by the time between snapshots. Or it does no such division (which would make much more sense) and just says "per second" because it does that for all other metrics.

Try to figure out how the value is calculated. As it is, all you can say is that you get a spike whenever there is a checkpoint (although checkpoints are spread in PostgreSQL), and the relative height of the spikes will tell you how long it took the operating system to write the data out to disk. Higher spikes can mean more database activity or intermittent slowness of the disk.